# Date and time not updating

Tags: java, date, time

My program uses dates to check when an engineer has visited a machine. The only problem with this is that the date does not remain up to date. The date and time that the machine displays is the exact time that the machine was started. Not when the button was clicked. Any assistance would be helpful.

Code:

```
package com.perisic.beds.peripherals;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.xmlrpc.WebServer;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient;

import com.perisic.beds.machine.CustomerPanel;


/**
 * A Simple Graphical User Interface for the Recycling Machine.
 * @author Group M
 *
 */
public class RecyclingGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5772727482959492839L;
    //CustomerPanel myCustomerPanel = new CustomerPanel(new Display());
    Display myDisplay = new Display();

    ReceiptPrinter printer = new ReceiptPrinter();
    ReceiptPrinter printer2 = new ReceiptPrinter();

    CustomerPanel myCustomerPanel = new CustomerPanel(myDisplay);
    CustomerPanel machineScreen = new CustomerPanel(printer2);
    CustomerPanel theConsole = new CustomerPanel(printer);
    CustomerPanel thePanel = new CustomerPanel(myDisplay);

    private String storedPasswd = "123"; // needs some thinking with encryption etc
    private String storedCookie = null; // some random string to be used for authentication
    private String sessionCookie = "";

    private int numberOfVisits;



    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    Date storedDate = date;
    /**
     * Web service to provide number of items in the machine. 
     * @param myCookie
     * @return
     */

    public int numberOfItems(String myCookie) {
        if( storedCookie == null ) { 
            return -1; 
        } else if( myCookie.equals(storedCookie)) { 
            return myCustomerPanel.getNumberOfItems(); 
        } 
        else { 
            return -1; 
        }
    }

    public int empty (String myCookie){
        if(storedCookie == null){
            return -1;
        }else if(myCookie.equals(storedCookie)){
            return myCustomerPanel.empty();
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Web service to authenticate the user with proper password. 
     * @param passwd
     * @return
     */

    public String login(String passwd) { 
        if( passwd.equals(storedPasswd)) { 
         storedCookie = "MC"+Math.random(); 
         System.out.println("Engineer has logged in on: " + dateFormat.format(date));
         storedDate = date;
         numberOfVisits ++;
         return storedCookie;
     } else { 
         return "Incorrect Password";
     }
    } 

    public String visits(String myCookie){
        if(numberOfVisits == 0){
            return "Engineer has not visited this machine";
        }else if(myCookie.equals(storedCookie)){
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVisits; i++){
            System.out.println("Engineer has visited on these dates: " + dateFormat.format(storedDate));
            }
            return storedCookie;
        }else{
            return "Engineer has visited on these date: " + dateFormat.format(storedDate);
        }
    }

     /**
      * Web service to logout from the system. 
      */

    public String logout(String myCookie ) { 
        if( storedCookie == null ) { 
            return "(no cookie set)"; 
        } else if( myCookie.equals(storedCookie)) { 
            System.out.println("Engineer has logged out on: " + dateFormat.format(date));
            storedCookie = null;  
            return "cookie deleted: OK"; 
        } 
        else { 
            return "could not delete anything; authentication missing"; 
        }
    }


    public static final String SUN_JAVA_COMMAND = "sun.java.command";

    //This method is used to restart the application.
    //It uses code that basically stores all of the necessary code it will need to successfully restart the application.
    //Rather then just using System.exit(0) which, by itself would simply close the entire application.
    //Using dispose() and new RecyclingGUI also doesn't work as it does not reload the JPanel upon restarting.
    public void restartApplication(Runnable runBeforeRestart) throws IOException{
        try {
            String java = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java";
            List<String> vmArguments = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
            StringBuffer vmArgsOneLine = new StringBuffer();
            for (String arg : vmArguments) {
                if (!arg.contains("-agentlib")) {
                    vmArgsOneLine.append(arg);
                    vmArgsOneLine.append(" ");
                }
            }
            final StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer("\"" + java + "\" " + vmArgsOneLine);
            String[] mainCommand = System.getProperty(SUN_JAVA_COMMAND).split(" ");
            if (mainCommand[0].endsWith(".jar")) {
            cmd.append("-jar " + new File(mainCommand[0]).getPath());
            } else {
                cmd.append("-cp \"" + System.getProperty("java.class.path") + "\" " + mainCommand[0]);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < mainCommand.length; i++) {
                cmd.append(" ");
                cmd.append(mainCommand[i]);
            }
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            if (runBeforeRestart!= null) {
                runBeforeRestart.run();
            }
        System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Error while trying to restart the machine", e);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /* Differentiate between the different buttons pressed and initiate appropriate
         * actions
         */
        try{
            XmlRpcClient server = new XmlRpcClient("http://localhost:100");
    //This code allows the engineer to login to the machine and when they do it reveals new buttons that only the engineer can use.
            if (e.getSource().equals(login)){
                String message;

                boolean loginSuccess = false;
                while(loginSuccess == false && (message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Login please"))!= null){
                    Vector parms1 = new Vector();
                    parms1.add(message);
                    Object result3 = server.execute("recycling.login", parms1);
                    String loginRequest = result3.toString();
                    if(loginRequest.equals("Wrong password")){
                        System.out.println("Wrong Password. Try Again!");
                    } else {
                        sessionCookie = loginRequest;
                        System.out.println("You are now logged in");
                        login.setVisible(false);
                        logout.setVisible(true);
                        reset.setVisible(true);
                        empty.setVisible(true);
                        items.setVisible(true);
                        loginSuccess = true;
                    }
                }
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(visits)){
                Vector params = new Vector();
                params.add(sessionCookie);
                Object result = server.execute("recycling.visits", params);
                System.out.println(result);


            //This logs the engineer out of the machine and hides some of the buttons
            }else if( e.getSource().equals(logout)) { 
                Vector params = new Vector(); 
                params.add(sessionCookie); 
                Object result = server.execute("recycling.logout", params ); 
                System.out.println("Logout: "+result);
                reset.setVisible(false);
                empty.setVisible(false);
                items.setVisible(false);
                login.setVisible(true);
                logout.setVisible(false);

                //This code tells the engineer how many items are currently in the machine.
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(items)){
                Vector params = new Vector(); 
                params.add(sessionCookie); 
                Object result = server.execute("recycling.numberOfItems", params ); 
                int resultInt = new Integer(result.toString()); 
                if( resultInt == -1 ) { 
                    System.out.println("Sorry no authentication there."); 
                } else { 
                    System.out.println("There are "+resultInt+" items in the machine");
                }

                //This if statement empties all items that have been put into the machine thus far and sets the item number property to 0
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(empty)){
                Vector params = new Vector();
                params.add(sessionCookie);
                Object result = server.execute("recycling.empty", params);
                int resultInt = new Integer(result.toString());
                if(resultInt == -1){
                    System.out.println("Sorry no authentication there.");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("The machine has been emptied.");
                }

                //This method coded above is called here.
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(reset)){
                restartApplication(null);


            }else if(e.getSource().equals(slot1)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.itemReceived(1);
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(slot2)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.itemReceived(2);
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(slot3)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.itemReceived(3);
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(slot4)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.itemReceived(4);
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(receipt)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.printReceipt();
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(display)) {
                this.myCustomerPanel = thePanel;
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(console)){
                myCustomerPanel = theConsole;
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(onScreen)){
                //once this button is clicked all output is linked back into the GUI
                myCustomerPanel = machineScreen;
                redirectSystemStreams();    
            }


        }catch (Exception exception) {
            System.err.println("JavaClient: " + exception);
        }
        // System.out.println("Received: e.getActionCommand()="+e.getActionCommand()+
        //                  " e.getSource()="+e.getSource().toString() ); 


    }

    //This Adds the controls (buttons) to the GUI
        JButton slot1 = new JButton("Can"); 
        JButton slot2 = new JButton("Bottle"); 
        JButton slot3 = new JButton("Crate");
        JButton slot4 = new JButton("Paper Bag");
        JButton receipt = new JButton("Print Receipt"); 
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        JButton logout = new JButton("Logout");
        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        JButton empty = new JButton("Empty");
        JButton items = new JButton("#Items");
        JButton visits = new JButton("visits");

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20,30);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        JButton display = new JButton("Print to Display");
        JButton console = new JButton("Print to GUI/Console");
        JButton onScreen = new JButton("Show On Screen");

        /** This creates the GUI using the controls above and
         *  adds the actions and listeners. this area of code also 
         *  Contains the panel settings for size and some behaviours.
        */
        public RecyclingGUI() {
            super();
            setSize(500, 600);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
            panel.add(slot1); 
            panel.add(slot2);
            panel.add(slot3);
            panel.add(slot4);

            slot1.addActionListener(this); 
            slot2.addActionListener(this); 
            slot3.addActionListener(this);
            slot4.addActionListener(this);

            panel.add(receipt); 
            receipt.addActionListener(this); 
            panel.add(display);
            display.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(console);
            console.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(onScreen);
            onScreen.addActionListener(this);

            /**Text Area controls for size, font style, font size
             * the text area also has a scroll bar just in case the user enters 
             * a large number of items
             */
            panel.add(scroll);
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            textArea.setFont(new Font("Ariel",Font.PLAIN, 14));
            scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

            panel.add(login);
            login.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(logout);
            logout.setVisible(false);
            logout.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(reset);
            reset.setVisible(false);
            reset.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(items);
            items.setVisible(false);
            items.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(empty);
            empty.setVisible(false);
            empty.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(visits);
            visits.addActionListener(this);

            getContentPane().add(panel);
            panel.repaint();

        }

    public static void main(String [] args ) { 
        RecyclingGUI myGUI = new RecyclingGUI(); 
        myGUI.setVisible(true); 
        try {
               System.out.println("Starting the Recycling Server..."); 
               WebServer server = new WebServer(100);
               server.addHandler("recycling", myGUI);
               server.start();
              } catch (Exception exception) {
               System.err.println("JavaServer: " + exception);
               }

    }
    /** This is the code that redirects where the code is displayed
     *  from the console to the textArea of the GUI. it does this by 
     *  creating a new set of output streams (for text and errors) which 
     *  are set as default when the redirectSystemStream method is called.
     *  (from a previous piece of work i did in my FDg, source = from a tutorial)
     */
    public void updateTextArea(final String text) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              textArea.append(text);
            }
          });
        }

        public void redirectSystemStreams() {
          OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
              updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
              updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
              write(b, 0, b.length);
            }
          };

          System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
          System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
        }

    public void print(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);

    }

}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` and also `DateTimeFormatter`; all are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never re-initialize `date`, you're just updating `storedDate` with the *existing* `date` in `login`. You could change this line in `login`

```
storedDate = date;
```

to

```
storedDate = new Date();
```

And then (I think) you can remove `date`.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` does not keep a persistent current time. `Date` is backed by a `long` that is set when the `Date` is instantiated and is never changed.

You can either make a `new Date()` in your logon method, so it would be created when the user logs on, or just use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current time as a `long`.