# Below code is printing static system time for every two seconds but i want to print Dynamic system time for every 2 seconds

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write a simple java program, that dynamically prints the current time every 2 seconds. It is in fact printing every 2 seconds, however it prints the exact same time instead of the current time.
I do not know why that is,
here is what i tried:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class curtime extends Thread {

public void run()
{
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     for (int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
public static void main(String args[])
{
        curtime cut = new curtime();
        cut.start();
}
}
```

Comment: What's the question? What's the problem in this code? Add a few words to explain your problem

Comment: `Thread.sleep(20000)` will wait **20** seconds, not 2.

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`. Since Java 8 (2014!) we have the new [Java time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Comment: Want to print dynamic System time for every two seconds up to 20 seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date and time not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944035/date-and-time-not-updating)

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

**That** call fetches the time.

Then you turn **that** time into a date and then into a string 10 times. 
You would have to fetch a new Calendar instance **within** the loop!

But in 2019, the real answer is to use `LocalDateTime.now()` instead. The Calendar/Date stuff is **seriously** outdated and not recommended to be used any more!